# jQuery facybox and galleriffic

Tags: javascript, jquery, conflict

There seems to be a conflict in two plugins I am trying to use.

facybox is a lighthouse plugin:
https://github.com/bitbonsai/facyBox/

that makes a div appear and darkens the rest of the page. Inside of that div, I would love to have a galleriffic slideshow:
http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/

Everything works fine if the galleriffic slide show is in an iframe inside of the div facybox uses, but it breaks if I try and initialize the galleriffic inside of the page that contains the div that facybox uses.

I am not very experienced in javascript so I was wondering if anyone could give me any tips on what to look for to resolve this conflict. Do situations like this arise when both plugins try to utilize a certain event?

Comment: there is some issues in fancybox plugins... instead of that try to use jquery colorbox plugin (http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox), its simple and useful

Comment: thx Dasarp ! if you post this as an answer to my question I'll accept it -- I ended up using color box!